# Exclude multiple sum rows when all zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to exclude a row in the query result if all 3 sum columns are zero.

```
Select Name
,sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2014-05-01') then 1 else 0 end) as 'First'
,sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2014-04-01') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Second'
,sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2013-05-01') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Third'
FROM [dbo].[Posting]
inner join dbo.Names on Name.NameId = Posting.NameId
where active = 1 
group by Name
order by Name
```

Comment: your query returns only one row. are you sure it's your requirement?

Comment: I updated the question to add more of the query.

Comment: se you can use this query:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may work for you :

```
select * from
( 
.......your query......
) as t
where First <> 0 or Second <> 0 or Third <> 0
```

Comment: This query displays the rows of all zeros, I want to exclude them from the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the expressions in the `having` clause:

```
having sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2014-05-01') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2014-04-01') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2013-05-01') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

However, you could write the conditions more simply as:

```
having sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= '2014-05-01' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= '2014-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= '2013-05-01' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Or, because the first encompasses the other two:

```
having sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= '2014-05-01' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Or, even more simply:

```
having min(date) <= '2014-05-01'
```

Also, you should use single quotes only for string and date names.  Don't use single quotes for column aliases (it can lead to confusion and problems).  Choose names that don't need to be escaped.  If you *have* to have a troublesome name, then use square braces.

Comment: Adding the having clause shows only the rows that have zeros for all the sum columns. I want to exclude only the rows that have zeros for all of the columns.

Comment: +1. 3rd and 4th options are good. I suggested the answer when he hasn't given the whole query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query:

```
with temp as 

(Select Name
,sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2014-05-01') then 1 else 0 end) as 'First'
,sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2014-04-01') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Second'
,sum(case when cast(Date as date) <= Convert(datetime, '2013-05-01') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Third'
FROM [dbo].[Posting]
inner join dbo.Names on Name.NameId = Posting.NameId
where active = 1 
group by Name
order by Name)

select * from temp where [first]+[second]+[third]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `Convert date` to `datetime`.

`cast(Date as date)` will convert columns date values to `yyyy-MM-dd` format

```
with CTE
as
(select 
sum(case when cast(Date as date) <=  '2014-05-01' then 1 else 0 end) as 'First'
,sum(case when cast(Date as date) <=  '2014-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Second'
,sum(case when cast(Date as date) <=  '2013-05-01' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Third' from myTable
)
where CTE.First=0 and CTE.Second=0 and CTE.Third=0
```